# Pair-friendly elliptic curves vs non friendly

Tags: elliptic-curves, pairings

Group law operations on pair-friendly elliptic curves are slower than in non friendly elliptic curves, but how much slower? Can't seem to find a performance comparison between the two for a given security parameter.

And what is the most efficient curve of each group?

Comment: What do you mean by "what is the most efficient curve of each group?" ?

Comment: I mean with the most efficient/fastest group law operations.

Comment: It depends also on the form of the curve (Montgomery, Edward, ...)